# Microsoft Entra Verificable ID with "Web" trust system showing a "ION" subject in it

Tags: azure-ad-verifiable-credentials

I have set up Microsoft Entra for my AD and configured all correctly with "Web" trust system (not "ION").

Then I have followed a simple sample from "Azure-Samples" GitHub at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-verifiable-credentials-dotnet (the first one).

All goes great and my did.json and other files are identified well, nevertheless my verified credential has always a subject from "ION", see the following screenshot:

[image: VC presented]

I'm currently using Microsoft Authenticator and I have been investigating though code in both entra mobile libraries (iOS and Android) and I do not see any alternative...

Could be a possible restriction for MS Entra Verified IDs or it is more a wallet related problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as expected. The Microsoft Authenticator and the Microsoft Entra Wallet Library uses did:ion long form for its did and that is what you are seeing as the subject.

Comment: Thank you @cljung ! Do you know if this is going to change or allow other types of `did` "types" in a future?